# FK constraint using replaced table's records?

Tags: db2, referential-integrity

[Edit:  Solved.  If you believe this question is not worthy of being left on SO, please comment and I'll remove it.  Otherwise, who knows, it might be useful to someone else.]

---

Environment: DB2 for IBMi

I have an issue where a foreign key constraint is not allowing an insert for some records that ***do*** have a matching key in the parent table.

History:

I created a php script to test uploading some records to the child table, and realized that my development's parent table was out of date and didn't have some of the records needed to satisfy the FK constraint.

So, using the green screen, I copied the production object to the development server.  I used `RSTOBJ` to put it in my library on the dev machine and then used `COPYF` to copy it over to the corresponding dev version of the production library. (I renamed the existing object first).

The new table's name and system name is the same as the old table was.

As far as I can tell, the parent table now has all the required rows to fulfill the FK constraint.  I ran queries to verify that the necessary rows are there.  ***They are present.***

However, when I try to insert a record in the child table that references a value that wasn't in the original table, the FK constraint complains.

Is there some kind of "refresh" that should be done to update the FK constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it actually ***was*** still referencing the old table.  When ***renaming the table*** in the green screen, all references to the table are updated in tables using it as a foreign key.

You must remove the old FK constraint and make a new one pointing to the correct table.

Comment: Restoring the object over top the existing would have work.  You could have also merged the data into the existing using an SQL `merge` or a `CPYF  MBROPT(*ADDUPD)`    Note: `MBROPT(*REPLACE)` wouldn't be valid with FK constraints.